# Notice with variables and numbers with precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

pretty simple syntax question here, since I am new to rails. In my controller, I have two variables that I am trying to display in a notice after a redirect. They are piece.title and piece.price (piece is my model). The price is a decimal, and so I want to display it with two digits after the decimal (like `<%= number_with_precision piece.price, :precision => 2 %>`.

My current code is:

```
redirect_to pieces_path, notice: "Thanks for buying #{piece.title} for #{piece.price}."
```

This works, but how do I get the price to two decimal places? When I try to do the number with precision, I get syntax errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using this:

```
'%.2f' % 10 
#=> "10.00"

"Thanks for buying #{piece.title} for #{'%.2f' % price}."
#=> "Thanks for buying Coffee for 10.00."
```

Change your notice to this

```
class YourControllerName
  def my_method
    #......
    redirect_to pieces_path, notice: "Thanks for buying #{piece.title} for #{'%.2f' % piece.price}."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting?  My guess is `price.piece` is nil because your code looks correct, assuming you are using it in your view and not your controller.  Also, if it's supposed to be money, you should use `number_to_currency`:

```
<%= number_to_currency piece.price, :precision => 2 %>
```

Comment: Phillip, this is in my controller. The code In my question has no erros, but I want to display the price to two decimal places. I tried to use the <%= %> tags, but it didn't recognize them in the controller. Do you know how to fix this?